# "Do you need travel support?" Questions on Conference Applications

Tags: conference, funding

I am applying for conferences now for the first time while I have my own grant. My grant is mainly for my living stipend but has some money set aside for travel over 4 years. I am starting to apply for conferences and they are asking if I need support. The technical answer is "no," but the more complicated answer is that to go to all the conferences I want to go to, then I will need support from some of these conferences in order to pay for it for the course of 4 years.

Do I just say "yes" despite the short answer? It's very clear I have this grant that has some travel money, but in the end it's not unlimited, but I don't want to come off as greedy.

*How detailed should a response to a travel support requirement inquiry be?*

Comment: Often just saying "yes" isn't the end of it; you are then given instructions on how to formally apply for support.  The application may then ask you about other funding available to you.

Comment: I think it's pretty crystal clear that it is intended to mean "Would you have hardhips attending the conference if we did not fund your travel?"

Answer (score 4):

What you should answer will depend on the conference you're attending and the country it is hosted in. Different conferences will have different amounts of money available for travel support and there is no single set of criteria that is used to determine who is eligible. Often travel support is aimed at students and researchers with a very low budget, for example those from poor countries. It is typically not intended for people who have the budget to attend several conferences, but want to attend more.

So figure out what the eligibility criteria are. If they're not listed on the conference website you can either just fill in "yes" and hope that you are provided with documents that provide further information.

But as is often the case, the simplest way might be to just ask. Send an email to the conference organizers asking what their criteria and intended target audience are for travel support.